# SQL Select Query with multiple rows selecting a single row

Tags: sql

I am sure this has been done before but maybe I am not sure I know what to ask.  I assume I am using the wrong terminology.

I am using a third party piece of software that won't let me display/export an entire table populated by a query.  It will let me pass a string in with a query in it.

It will let me select a single row using:

```
SELECT * FROM [<dbname>].[dbo].[<tablename>] where [<Key>] = " + i
```

It will then let me select the column in that single row by name allowing me to use a nested loop to import the data.  I can get the row count back from a specific query using this software, so it makes it easy.  That all seems to be working fine.

However, I would like to add some search functionality which would let me select by data in the other non-key columns.  I have tried using:

```
Select Top (1) ...... where [<Column name I want to search>] = Search term
```

but that only gives me the first row.  I am looking for a way to select the second/third/nth row using an integer from my program

Comment: Try `OFFSET n ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` at the end. (And skip TOP 1.)

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used.